# C# Sql Server "loading window"

Tags: c#, sql

This is my first post here, but I've using this site regularly to help me with my own app's, and I should say that this site has been a great help to me, so thanks to everyone.

Now my question:
I'm developing my first software app that exchanges data between a sql server and the app itself. It's beeing developed in C#. Saving or retreiving data from the sql server database is no problem. 
What I want is a way to inform the user of the delay between the local machine (where the app is installed) and the server. I can make some animations or simply display some text messages. What I need help with is how to create the code that activates/fires/runs when that server communication time is running.

If you can't understand the idea, picture a video game. When it's loading (in some games) you can see the loading screen before the game starts. I need some code that displays that "loading window" when the the app is downloading or uploading data from/to the server.

I would appreciate any code example or web site recommendation.

PS: Sorry for the extensive text, but I want to make sure everyone understand so I don't have to repeat it again :P

Comment: You should use a new Form with a ProgressBar object.  You will also have handle cross thread requests, I'm sure a quick search will show some examples (off hand it's something like `if (this.InvokeRequired) { this.Invoke(aDelegateToMyFunction); } else { /*prossesing code here*/ }`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me thank you for your replies.

Toby your answer got me thinking about thread monitoring my sql connections but it was a bit tricky and confusing since the app is still in develop and will use a lot more connections.

S.Amani answer it wasn't quite what I want, but thanks to that I found a easier way. I created a form (could be anything else), placed a label saying: Saving To Data Base, took out the top bar, defined location and defined it's parent to be disabled when shown and enabled when closed. The following code is what I put inside my DataBaseInteractionClass

```
private Wait myCustomWaitDialog = new Wait(); // My Waiting form

private void SaveToDatabase(myObjectToSave obj) // Method called to save data do DB
{
    // Create the connections and queries
    (...)
    // This is what I did
    // Show Waiting Form
    myCustomWaitDialog.Show();
    // Instanciate the command that will carry the query and to DB
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Queries.GetData(code), conn);
    // This is important
    //Create event that will fire when the command completes
    command.StatementCompleted += new StatementCompletedEventHandler(command_StatementCompleted);
    // Execute the transaction
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    // Rest of the code (validations, close connections, try/catch, etc
    (...)
}

void command_StatementCompleted(object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is the method that closes my Waiting Dialog 
    myCustomWaitDialog.CloseDialog();
    myCustomWaitDialog.Dispose();
}
```

It's not quite what I want yet, but is the best solution that I found so far. For now it will do :)
Anyway, thanks for the replies and I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

- **[How do I implement a progress bar in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c)**
- **[How to create a smooth progress bar in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323116)**
- **[ProgressBar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx)**

Comment: That's not ... good? Anyway, no up-vote from me because vanilla links don't cut it. Please include summaries and/or relevant excerpts in an answer (or put links in a comment).

Comment: Actually first times on SO I got downvotes by providing only links.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a simple `PleaseWait` class 2 years ago, but I didn't update this class, It works very well, have look hope this will give you an idea to implement your logic.

```
public partial class frmWait : Form
{
    public frmWait()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool _isMoving = false;
    int _moveStart_x = 0;
    int _moveStart_y = 0;


    private void tmrProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (barProgress.Value == barProgress.Maximum)
            barProgress.Value = barProgress.Minimum;
        else
            barProgress.Value += 1;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        PleaseWait.Abort();
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
            p.ClassStyle += 0x20000;
            p.ExStyle += 0x8000000;
            return p;
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 132;

        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCHITTEST:
                if (m.Result.ToInt32() == 1)
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(2);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void panelEx1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _isMoving = true;
            _moveStart_x = e.X;
            _moveStart_y = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void panelEx1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _isMoving = false;
    }

    private void pnlContainer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isMoving)
            this.Location = new Point(Location.X + e.X - _moveStart_x, Location.Y + e.Y - _moveStart_y);
    }
}

public class PleaseWait
{
    #region Static Operations
    private static Boolean _isAborted = false;
    private static Boolean _isVisible = false;
    private static frmWait _waitForm;
    private static String _waitingState = "";
    private static Boolean _autoClose = false;
    private static Boolean _cancelable = false;
    private static System.Threading.Thread _waiterThred;

    public delegate void CancelButtonPressed();

    public static event CancelButtonPressed OnCancel;

    public static Boolean AutoClose
    {
        get { return PleaseWait._autoClose; }
        set { PleaseWait._autoClose = value; }
    }
    public static string WaitingState
    {
        get { return PleaseWait._waitingState; }
        set { PleaseWait._waitingState = value; }
    }
    public static bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        internal set { _isVisible = value; }
    }

    public static void ShowPleaseWait()
    {
        ShowPleaseWait("", _autoClose, false);
    }

    public static void ShowPleaseWait(string waitingState)
    {
        ShowPleaseWait(waitingState, _autoClose, false);
    }

    public static void ShowPleaseWait(bool autoClose)
    {
        ShowPleaseWait("", autoClose, false);
    }

    public static void ShowPleaseWait(string waitingState, bool autoClose, bool cancelable)
    {
        if (_waiterThred != null)
        {
            if (_isVisible)
            {
                // the please wait it woking, just continue and apply the changes
                _waitingState = waitingState;
                _autoClose = autoClose;
                _cancelable = cancelable;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _waiterThred.Abort();
                _waiterThred = null;
            }
        }

        _waitingState = waitingState;
        _autoClose = autoClose;
        _cancelable = cancelable;
        _isAborted = false;
        _isVisible = false;

        if (_autoClose)
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);



        _waiterThred = new System.Threading.Thread(DisplayWaitingForm);
        _waiterThred.IsBackground = true;
        _waiterThred.Name = "Please Wait....";
        _waiterThred.Start();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    public static void Abort()
    {
        _isAborted = true;
    }

    private static void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_autoClose)
            _isAborted = true;
    }


    private static void DisplayWaitingForm()
    {
        if (_waitForm != null)
        {
            if (!_waitForm.IsDisposed)
                _waitForm.Dispose();
            _waitForm = null;
            _isVisible = false;
        }
        try
        {
            if (_isAborted)
                return;

            _waitForm = new frmWait();
            if (_cancelable)
            {
                _waitForm.btnCancel.Enabled = true;
                _waitForm.btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(btnCancel_Click);
            }
            try
            {
                _isVisible = true;
                _waitForm.Show();
                _waitForm.Focus();
                while (!_isAborted)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
                    _waitForm.lblMessage.Text = _waitingState;
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    _waitForm.lblMessage.Text = _waitingState;
                }
                _isVisible = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                FreeWaitingForm();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isVisible = false;
        }
    }

    static void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_waitForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            _waitForm.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(btnCancel_Click), new object[] { e });
        }
        else
        {
            if (OnCancel != null)
                OnCancel.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private static void FreeWaitingForm()
    {
        _waitingState = "";
        _isVisible = false;
        if (_waitForm == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _waitForm.Hide();
        if (!_waitForm.IsDisposed)
            _waitForm.Dispose();
        _waitForm = null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

use like following code :

```
PleaseWait.ShowPleaseWait("Please wait", true, false);
// If second param is true then it will close the form automatically.
// If third param is true the it will expose a cancel button, so you can cancel your Asynchronous operations.
```

I didn't insert design code, you can understand by looking at code.

hope this help.