# Updating the UI at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a C# Winforms application.

In this application I opened one form in ShowDialog mode and when I click on the OK button then it starts the process of importing contacts from a GridView to the database (the number of rows may be up to 15,000).

The problem is that when the process of importing starts I increment the value of progressBar in a loop but if the form loses focus and I once again set the focus to that form then the progress bar is not updated.

How can I update the progress bar even when the form loses focus?

Comment: WinForms or WPF Application? ANYWAY answer is - do it from a separate thread, there are a lot of the same questions - TRY TO SEARCH

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker. Have a look [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Application.DoEvents()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) every now and then, but you really should use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I suppose you've been downvoted because of `Application.DoEvents`

Comment: @username: Is `Application.DoEvents()` bad? It causes an otherwise 'unresponsive' application to respond from time to time.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie In such cases there are much better ways to update UI. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/c-application-doevents

Comment: @username: Thanks for enlightening me. In my early days of coding, I'd use `Application.DoEvents()` just about everywhere. Thankfully, I never ran into any problems doing that. I unconsciously use threads now but never thought of any repercussions of using `Application.DoEvents()`.