# Oscillating horizontal green glow whilst something is loading c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

When loading something such as a software update in Windows 7 there is often an oscillating green glow effect in a horizontal bar. Is this a standard control that can be utilized in C#? If not, how can it be incorporated into a C# app.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This control is called `ProgressBar`.

If you are using WPF the property `IsIndeterminate` has to be set to true to have a "running green glow".

Comment: So I guess that this is a WPF feature and not available in the dot net 4 framework progress bar under c#?

Comment: @Andy You can have a `ProgressBar` control both in WPF and WinForms. Both UI technologies are provided in .NET framework 4. It's your decision which of those technics you will use to build your user interface.

Comment: I think that you answered my question nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implemented this using **BackgroundWorker** to update a progress bar ("the green glowing horizontal bar), and the same time keep the application main thread responsive. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c), or google around BackgroundWorker + Progress bar.

Comment: But this isn't necessary when using ProgressBar control in WPF!

Comment: I was interested in how to implement the visual green glow effect. The BackgroundWorker is standard stuff to handle code that takes an indeterminate time to complete without freezing the app. and having the ability to report progress. I am using the ProgressPercentage value with enums to display text messages in the status bar about what has happened so far.