# First time multithreader

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am trying to use threading for the first time, and came up with this:

```
Thread myThread  = new Thread(() =>
  {
    test = Class1.getNumbers(param1, param 2);
    MessageBox.Show(test.toString());
  });
```

This doesn't do anything for me though. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're missing the call to `Start`. Try adding `myThread.Start()` after you define `myThread`.

Comment: You are trying to show a message box from a worker thread. UI elements can only be created on the main thread.

Comment: For learning threading in the .NET platform, I highly recommend reading through this: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/index.shtml

Comment: @lucas1024 : But `MessageBox.Show()` is a thread-safe static method.

Comment: What do I do if I want to add some data from the thread to the UI? Do I have to pass the data from the thread to the main thread?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper : _What do I do if I want to add some data from the thread to the UI?_ That's a separate question and it has been asked & answered here many times already.

Comment: i just wanted to add that I dig the title of your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this [free chapter from a very good book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) (honest plug - no inscentive here):

It's consice and gives you the know-how you want in an incremental way so you don't go too high level too fast.  The answer your question is in the first few paragraphs...

Comment: Maybe I am going at this the wrong way... I just want to update a progress bar while executing a method.

Comment: if you don't give a hoot about threads, then go for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c

Comment: This is what I needed. I obviously need to learn more before attempting this!

Answer (score 6):

You didn't start the thread.

```
myThread.Start();
```

(You also have a syntax error on the MessageBox call...)

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to use threading for the first time

Try to avoid using the Thread class directly. That is rarely needed.
Look into:

- Backgroundworker
- Task Parallel Library
- ThreadPool

More or less in that order.

They all provide layers on top of threading to help you.

Comment: I think in the mind of a beginner this might confuse because avoiding the "Thread class" and avoiding "Multi threading" are distinct but sound the same... just a thought - another thought - it might be a bad thing to skip the Thread class along the same lines as learning EF without ever learning rdbms/sql... (i'm not trying to critisize, just thinking..)

Comment: @Gabriel: Yes, a good learning track would be to use the Thread _in a Console App_. And then use the Bgw in WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the thread by calling `Start`.

Also, it is important to note that `MessageBox.Show` pumps messages. That is why it is working correctly<sup>1</sup> without an explicit call to `Application.Run` on that thread. Most UI forms and controls do not work this way though. In general do not attempt to access or create any UI elements from a worker thread.

---

<sup>1</sup>*A `MessageBox` can technically work from a thread other than the main UI thread, but it can cause some weird problems. For example, this message box could get stuck behind a modal dialog displayed by the UI thread. It is for this reason, among others, that it is not advised to display UI elements from a worker thread even if they are done so with self pumping calls like `Form.ShowDialog` or `MessageBox.Show`.*