# Getting a progress bar to start on a button click

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I currently have a button object that starts a wav file playing, as well as a progress bar and a timer, all of which are toolbox objects in Visual Studio 2010. The problem is that, when I open the form, the progress bar automatically starts filling up. How can I get it to start only when I click on the button?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 private void playsong1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer sndplayer = new SoundPlayer(Programming_assignment.Properties.Resources.Back_In_Black);
        sndplayer.Play();

        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (progressBar1.Value < 256)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps u can check here "How do I implement a progress bar in C#? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c "

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `timer1.Enabled = true` or `timer1.Start()` in form's constructor or Load event handler. BTW check timer's `Enabled` property in designer - maybe you set it to `true` by default.

Comment: I had a look in the designer and the timer enabled property was set to false. I've put in the same thing for the progress bar as well, i.e. 'progressBar1.Enabled = true', would this help? Also would having an if statement inside the button click void be of any use?

Comment: No, disabling progress bar will not solve your issue. Just go and find all usages of `timer1` variable and check where you enable timer or start it.

Comment: Just gone through it all and found it, i'd set it to true right at the start! Thanks a lot man, you really helped a noobie programer out!