# How to refresh the label text during button click event several times in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my code 1 button is there which has a huge code which takes too much time to execute,so i want to display processing status on web form,i used timer control but that will be not used with session variables.Please suggest.
My code is quite like this-

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(i=o;i<100;i++)
       {
         label1.Text=" "+ i + " th processing start";
        //code execution
         label1.Text=" " + i + " th processing complete ";

       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Right now your question is very off topic. HINT: Show code

Comment: Without existing code, nobody can help you

Comment: Using this code, the code execution block will run 100 times...

Comment: Do you mean you want a [progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c)?

Comment: Yes I want progress Bar which will display for which i'th value code will be currently execute .And code execution block is also execute 100 times.

Comment: If you want star symbol which is rotating until the result will load then let me know..

Comment: No dude,I want to display for which i'th value the code will execute...